# React typescript hashmap title as key and values inside

Tags: reactjs, typescript, hashmap

I'm trying to display multiple items belonging to one element, i.e values belonging to key.  The key in this case is the title like

### Electronics

prod1

prod2

prod3

### Home Appliance

prod4

prod5

prod6

So I have a type with an array of elements, one of the elements is the title, while the other elements are displayed under

```
enum ProductCatagory {
   Electronics = "Electronics" ,
   HomeAppliance = "HomeAppliance"
}

export type Product= {
    pId: number,
    productName: string
}

 type MyHashMap= {
    [id: string] : items[]
}

 function ProductClass() {
    const myHash: MyHashMap= {}
    const obj: Product= {
      "0": { "pId": 0, "productName": "prod1", "catagory": "Home Appliance" },
      "1": { "pId": 1, "productName": "prod2", "catagory": "Home Appliance" },
      "2": { "pId": 2, "productName": "prod3", "catagory": "Home Appliance" }
      "3": { "pId": 3, "productName": "prod1", "catagory": "Electronics" },
      "4": { "pId": 4, "productName": "prod2", "catagory": "Electronics" },
      "5": { "pId": 5, "productName": "prod3", "catagory": "Electronics" }
    };
    obj.map(s => {
        if (!myHash[s.catagory]) {
            myHash[s.catagory] = []
        }
        myHash[s.catagory].push(s)
    })
    const electronics= obj[ProductCatagory.Electronics].map(e => { return e} );
    const homeAppliance= obj[ProductCatagory.HomeAppliance].map(h => { return h} );
    const differentiator = (electronics||homeAppliance) : (electronics|| homeAppliance)
    return (
        {<h1>{titlehere}</h1>
        <ul>
            {
               differentiator.map((prod, key) => {
                    return (
                        <h1 key={key}>{prod}</h1>
                    )
               })
            }
        </ul>
    )
}
```

What I have tried so far is using switch statement, but I just don't know how to print out only the key in the title and products underneath. But I need help with how, or any pointers would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out for anyone interested.

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

So the answer would be

```
enum ProductCatagory {
   Electronics = "Electronics" ,
   HomeAppliance = "HomeAppliance"
}

export type Product= {
    pId: number,
    productName: string
}

 type MyHashMap= {
    [id: string] : items[]
}

 function ProductClass() {
    const myHash: MyHashMap= {}
    const obj: Product= {
      "0": { "pId": 0, "productName": "prod1", "catagory": "Home Appliance" },
      "1": { "pId": 1, "productName": "prod2", "catagory": "Home Appliance" },
      "2": { "pId": 2, "productName": "prod3", "catagory": "Home Appliance" }
      "3": { "pId": 3, "productName": "prod1", "catagory": "Electronics" },
      "4": { "pId": 4, "productName": "prod2", "catagory": "Electronics" },
      "5": { "pId": 5, "productName": "prod3", "catagory": "Electronics" }
    };
    obj.map(s => {
        if (!myHash[s.catagory]) {
            myHash[s.catagory] = []
        }
        myHash[s.catagory].push(s)
    })
    const electronics= obj[ProductCatagory.Electronics].map(e => { return e} );
    const homeAppliance= obj[ProductCatagory.HomeAppliance].map(h => { return h} );
    const differentiator = (electronics||homeAppliance) : (electronics|| homeAppliance)

const renderProducts= Object.entries(myHash).map(([catagory, productName], key) => {
    return (
        <divkey={key}>
               <h3>{catagory}</h3>
               <p>{productName.map(p => {return p.productName})}</p>
        </div>
    )
})

return (
    <>  
        {renderProducts}
    </>   
);
}
```